# jQuery value pick up

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is code:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<script>
    var name = $("#name").val();
</script>
```

After page is loaded, I type in value in input box. This is what I type in chrome console after value

```
console.log(name);
```

I get empty string

Comment: the `name` variable is assigned immediately when the script is interpreted, and would not change if you type a different value into the textbox.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<script>
    $(document).on('keyup', '#name', function(){
        name = $(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

This will assign the value of `#name` to the variable `name` only once a value has been typed in.

Comment: The variable "name" here still isn't global, it's still not going to be accessible by the Chrome console. Your solution is correct (I'm guessing) to what he's wanting, as a final solution, but not to the issue he's explained.

Comment: since he doesn't use `var name` here, the variable is actually global, and can be accessed from anywhere, including the console.

Comment: @Chris - Susanoh13 is correct, I omitted `var` on purpose so that it would be available globally.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QJ3BT/ - type console.log(name) in your Chrome/Firebug/whatever console.

Comment: @Chris - that's because it's within an iframe. Put it into a plain html page and it will work fine.

Comment: jsFiddle is sandboxed. `name` is still global, but you can't access it directly from the browser console. :)

Comment: Completely forgot jsFiddle was an iframe, I've thought, for months, that you couldn't get global variables from the console... well, that's me told! Apologies to all, and thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$("#name").val()` after you typed, otherwise it will be loaded when the page loads and you get an empty string as the input is empty at this time.

Answer (score -1):

That won't work as the Chrome console has no idea what your JavaScript values are, their scope isn't global. You need to write your console.log(name) in your script tag, or declare your name variable in the console (and the assignment) and log that.

Comment: Actually, this isn't the issue. Since `name` isn't being declared in a local scope, it is in fact global. However, the script to pull `name` out of the text field is being run as soon as the page is loaded, and long before the user has time to type anything into the text field, meaning it will be empty.

Comment: Understood, this answer was my mistake.